# Unable to find the project path for mstest.exe/tcm.exe

Tags: tfs, mstest, tfs-2015, tcm

I tried to push the test result (*.trx) to MTM by command line. I used `msttest /publish` or `tcm run /publish`. With both I can't get the correct project path, anyone know how to find the path?

Attempted:

```
/collection:"mtms://companyName.visualstudio.com:443"
    /teamproject:"MyProject/Testing/testplan"
```

> Error: TF249051: No URL can be found that corresponds to the following
>   server name:

Tried to remove `mtms://` and just used `https://companyName.visualstatudio.com`:

> The following team project cannot be found:

How do I find out what is the correct project path?

Comment: Did you figure out your issue? You should include your collection in the url  such as`/collection: https://companyName.visualstatudio.com:443/YourCollection` .It's a **collection level url** not TFS server url. And also simply use the teamproject name for /teamproject option, such as `/teamproject:"MyProject"`

Answer (score 0):

The `/publish` command is used to **associate test runs/results with builds**. MTM is displaying test results that are associated with test plans/suites which are somewhat independent of builds.

> **/publish: [ server name]**
>
> Use the /publish option to publish test data to the database for the
>   team project collection associated with the project's Team Foundation
>   Server. When you use the /publish option, you must correctly specify
>   the name of the Team Foundation Server. The correct format depends on
>   whether the Team Foundation Server has been registered on the client
>   computer, as described here: [Command-Line options for publishing test
>   results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243151(v=vs.120).aspx)

Using this command the results will successfully published to build.The published result is viewed in your build summary, but they **don't appear in MTM**. There is no way to view the result in MTM.  Please refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9b7a5ae4-e2a7-4ddb-b397-085bea669fd9/possible-to-run-tests-through-mstestexe-and-see-results-in-microsoft-test-manager#b7d95c64-8390-41a9-a43f-3e6b57ddd73a) similar question.

**TCM** is a command line interface to running tests, similar to mstest, but it runs the tests through the infrastructure you set up in MTM.  To publish .trx files to MTM/TFS, you're going to have to use `tcm.exe` not `mstest.exe` to get what you're after.  Sample command as below:

```
tcm run /publish /suiteid:XXXX /configid:X /resultowner:"ABC XYZ" /resultsfile:C:\TempResult.trx /collection:http://<<TFS URL>> /teamproject:"My Project" /runowner:"ABC XYZ" /build:<<Build Number>> /builddefinition:<<Build Definition Name>>
```

**Note:** please double check your server url is suitable.